# Programmatically changing page in JQM

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 app with some pages. I have a page (#menyside) in index.html, which I have bound an event to:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#menyside', function(event){
        // check local storage, and some times do this:
    $.mobile.changePage("otherPage.html", { transition: "slideup"} );
}
});
```

I check for some values in local storage, and based on those values I might want to change the page programmatically. This works when I open the app for the first time, but not when I reopen the app (i.e. the document is already loaded in the browser, but it is reloaded)

Am I binding to the wrong event? I tried to look at the events in the documentation but didn't really find something better...

Comment: Is #menyside an id of your page? Because if it is there isn't anything with your code. Did you receive any error?

Comment: @Gajotres : yes, #menyside is the page in index.html. I can't see any errors. I think it only happens on a mobile device, not on a desktop browser.